# Matlab--syntax error in calculating population density using gridded population data?

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matalab to calculate population density, and the data available right now is the lat/lon of each grid cell of the earth, and the population in each grid (log format), and what I need to do is calculate the area of the grid first and then convert population to population density. Here's the code:

```
area= 111.11*111.11*cosd(GPW.lat)
Population_Density=log(10.^(GPW.Log10_population)./area)
```

Matlab says there's error in using the ./ syntax.

"Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree."

But I don't quite understand how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `GPW.Log10_population` and `GPW.lat` are of different sizes. Try

```
size(GPW.Log10_population)
size(GPW.lat)
```

And see if they agree. If they don't you may be making some wrong assumptions.